# List style type decimal after the actual content of the li

Tags: css, html-lists

This is probably impossible but I have to ask. 
Lets say I have a list:

```
<ul>
<li>hello world</li>
<li>hello world</li>
</ul>
```

If I use the css:

```
.list {
list-style-type:decimal
}
```

It will render:

```
1. hello world
2. hello world
```

Can I make the numbers appear after the actual content of the li and even better without the dot, like:

```
hello world 1
hello world 2
```

Ty!

Do you have any ideas... if this is not possible with CSS maybe with jquery?

Comment: Hmm...not sure about css, but it's definitely possible with jQuery!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to use `:after` and [CSS counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters):

```
ol {
    counter-reset: pancakes;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li:after {
    content: counter(pancakes);
    counter-increment: pancakes;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DePqL/1/

Might be difficult to get the exact effect you're after though.

CSS3 offers [a lot more options for list markers](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-pseudoelement) but browser support is rather spotty at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with css **generated content**

```
.list {
    padding:2em;
    list-style-type:none;
    counter-reset:nums;    
}

.list li:after{
    counter-increment:nums;
    content: " " counter(nums);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xrbm2/2/

Comment: This would not allow nested lists, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xrbm2/3/ (Just a note.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a CSS solution, but since you mentioned jquery, how about something like the following:

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).append(" " + (index + 1));
});
```

Loop through each `<li>` and use the `index` (0 based) parameter to append the number after the content

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Html:

```
<ul id="theul">
    <li>hello world</li>
    <li>hello world</li>
    <li>hello world</li>
</ul>
```

Js:

```
var i=1;
    $("#theul li").each(function() {
      $(this).append(" " + i);
        i = i+1;
});
```

Demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VNwtY/)

Comment: `.each` passes the index as a parameter to the function. No need to use `i`.

Comment: @WilliamVanRensselaer: Lol, I do not really know about jQuery, but I try to answer. Thank you for mentioning.

Answer (score -1):

You will probably have to create the effect yourself. Here is an example. [http://jsfiddle.net/9NmYm/](http://jsfiddle.net/williamvanr/9NmYm/).

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
}
ul li span.num {
    float: right;
}

<ul>
    <li>Hello World<span class="num">1</span></li>
    <li>Hello World<span class="num">2</span></li>
    <li>Hello World<span class="num">3</span></li>
</ul>
```

Of course, if you have a long list, you can use JavaScript or jQuery to dynamically add numbers.